# How to refer to `defaultProps` inside `defaultProps`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to refer `defaultProps` inside `defaultProps`? i.e.

```
work.defaultProps = {
    start_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') || '',
    start_time: this.defaultProps.start_date.format('h:mm a')
};
```

Comment: do you want to make the recursifs calls?

Answer (score 1):

"this" won't work for you because it refers to the context, in which the code runs, not to the object you're instantiating.

This might work

```
work.defaultProps = {
    start_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') || '',
    start_time: work.defaultProps.start_date.format('h:mm a')
};
```

However you better not rely on the order of initialization of object members.

A safer, though less elegant way to do that would be

```
work.defaultProps = {}
work.defaultProps.start_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') || '';
work.defaultProps.start_time = work.defaultProps.start_date.format('h:mm a');
```